# CouchDB reduce function useful in this scenario?

Tags: couchdb

I want to store votes in CouchDB. To get round the problem of incrementing a field in one document and having millions of revisions, each vote will be a seperate document:

```
{
  _id: "xyz"
  type: "thumbs_up"
  vote_id: "test"
}
```

So the actual document itself is the vote. The result I'd like is basically an array of: vote_id, sumOfThumbsUp, sumOfThumbsDown

Now I think my map function would need to look like:

```
if(type=="thumbs_up" | type =="thumbs_down"){
    emit(vote_id, type)
}
```

Now here's the bit I can't figure out what to do, should I build a reduce function to somehow sum the vote types, keeping in mind there's two types of votes.

Or should I just take what's been emited from the map function and put it straight into an array to work on, ignoring the reduce function completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for map-reduce! Having each document represent a vote is the right way to go in my opinion, and will work with CouchDB's strengths.

I would recommend a document structure like this:

### Documents

#### UPVOTE

```
{
  "type": "vote",
  "vote_id": "test",
  "vote": 1
}
```

#### DOWNVOTE

```
{
  "type": "vote",
  "vote_id": "test",
  "vote": -1
}
```

- I would use a document type of "vote", so you can have other document types in your database (like the vote category information, user information, etc)
- I kept "vote_id" the same
- I made the value field called "vote", and just used `1`/`-1` instead of "thumbs_up" or "thumbs_down" (really doesn't matter, you can do whatever you want and it will work just fine)

### View

#### Map

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.type === "vote") {
        emit(doc.vote_id, doc.vote);
    }
}
```

#### Reduce

```
_sum
```

You end up with a result like this for your map function:

[image: map results]

And if you reduce it:

[image: reduce results]

As you add more vote documents with more vote_id variety, you can query for a specific vote_id by using: `/:db/_design/:ddoc/_view/:view?reduce=true&group=true&key=":vote_id"`

Comment: Brilliantly explained solution